# Scala - Display the folders if it has files

Tags: scala

I have a scenario where the folder has 3 files [ .csv, .ctl, .recon ].

Folder : e.g., 20190101, 20190102, 20190103.
Each folder has 3 files in it.

The scenario is sometimes the folder has only 2 or 1 file and I need to display those folders.

I used `x.length>=3` to display folder which has all 3 files.

Is there a way to check using `filter(x=>x.contains(".ctl") && (".csv")` and display the folder names?

Comment: What is that `x` ?

Comment: sorry, x, I mean folder name

Comment: If `x` is folder name... then you need to put more effort into better explaining the question and your current code.

Comment: Please post enough code so that we can reproduce your `x.length>=3` results. From there it should be easy to enhance it as requested. (Always remember that code posted to SO should be [MCR](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "rootDirectory" that has the following structure of sub-folders containing files:

[image]

If you want to display names of directories that contains at least one ".ctl" and one ".csv" file, something like this would work:

```
val rootDirectory = new File("/home/username/rootDirectory")
val directories = rootDirectory.listFiles.filter(_.isDirectory)
val validDirectories = directories.filter{
  dir=>
    dir.listFiles.filter(_.getName.toLowerCase.endsWith("csv")).length>0 &&   dir.listFiles.filter(_.getName.toLowerCase.endsWith("ctl")).length>0
 }.map(directory=> directory.getName)

validDirectories.foreach{
  name =>
    println(name)
}
```

This code will print out the names of directories containing both ctl and csv files:

[image]

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. My simple code below , 

var u = Array("asd.csv","asd.ctl","asd.recon")                                                                  

|| working:
===========

u.filter(x=>(x.contains("csv") || x.contains("ctl")))
res25: Array[String] = Array(asd.csv, asd.ctl)

&& not working:
===============

scala> u.filter(x=>(x.contains("csv") && x.contains("ctl")))
res24: Array[String] = Array()

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear, so this answer is based on what I understand as your requirement. This solution works well, but maybe you didn't setup inputs properly. I've updated my answer to display what is input and how output looks like.